# Maven from command line with multiple eclipse projects

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, command-line

Suppose I have the following file/project structure.

```
MSPCommon/trunk/pom.xml
MSPWebManager/trunk/pom.xml
```

and MSPWebManager depends on MSPCommon and MSPCommon and MSPWebManager are in the same directory.

I have imported these projects into eclipse, and within eclipse I can successfully do maven builds on MSPWebManager (like `mvn clean compile`) IF I do it the following way. Go to Run -> Run configurations, type in the maven commands AND select `Resolve Workspace artifacts`.

That's all great, but what I would like to be able to do is run the same maven commands from the command line. So I navigate to the MSPWebManager/trunk directory, do a mvn command like `mvn clean compile` and this is the result:

[image]

As you can see there is one other local jar that is missing, but for simplicity I only included one in this question because I'm assuming the fix is the same for them all.

Also, if I do some type of build within eclipse but I do NOT check the `Resolve Workspace artifacts`, I get the same error as I do on the command line.

Any suggestions on how to get this to work from the command line?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to the module MSPCommon and run a `mvn clean install` then go to MSPWebManager and do the `mvn clean compile`

`mvn install` resolves the dependencies and installs your build inside of your .m2 repository / folder.

Comment: Wow that was easy. I had to climb the dependency tree a bit to get it to work but that was the fix! Thanks